# VS Code Shortcuts for Efficient Debug Run Test Workflow in Rust

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

[image]

I am having trouble running tests or debugging a specific test. In particular I have to click these buttons to single out run specific tests. But when I am debugging or searching for elsewhere, and once the debugging session is over, I have to get back here and click this thing to run this again. Which takes a while to navigate back here to click click click.

How do I streamline and efficiently single out and run tests and debug them, with shortcuts or specific tasks of sorts.

For example test only scripts maybe somehow in Rust.

Answer (score 0):

I use VIM extension so the way I figured out a way is to use VIM Marks

mA  to set a global mark (or ma to set a local mark for that file)

then  'A    or 'a   to return back to mark.